# Sorting a collection after transform

Tags: mongodb, coffeescript, meteor

I have a collection that uses transform to instantiate the documents from classes. Those instances then set new attributes, data fetched from 3rd part apis and made reactive.

Now, I need to sort those objects based on a method that retrieve the reactive data. But I cannot do a collection find.sort, or use collection-hooks, because it operates on the document before transforming it, hence the method is not available.

Therefore, it seems to me that the only way to sort that collection based on that data which is not in mongo, is to override the UI.each element and adding sorting there. But I'm quite new with Meteor, and do not really know how UI.each works and how to override it to implement that sorting method.

Below a simplified example from my code:

**model**

```js
class @BaseCrypto

  constructor: (@address) ->
    @keys =
      balance: "Processing..."
    @deps = {}

  ensureDeps: (key) ->
    if not @deps[key]
      @deps[key] = new Deps.Dependency()
      @set_balance()

  get_balance: ->
    """Retrieve value set from @set_balance()"""
    @ensureDeps "balance"
    @deps.balance.depend()
    return @keys.balance

  set_balance: (url, lambda_balance) ->
    cls = this
    Meteor.call "call_url", url, (err, result) ->
      if err
        throw new Meteor.Error err.error, err.reason
      else
        cls.keys.balance = lambda_balance result
        cls.deps.balance.changed()
```

**collection**

```js
@Addresses = new Meteor.Collection "addresses",
  transform: (doc) ->
      doc = BaseCrypto doc.address
      doc.set_balance url, lambda_balance
    return doc
```

**helper**

```js
Template.coinsManager.helpers
  donationAddresses: ->
      Addresses.find {}
```

**template**

```jade
template(name="coinsManager")

    div
        div.addresses
            {{#each donationAddresses}}
            {{> addressItem}}
            {{/each}}
```

How can I get `{{#each}}` to sort my addresses depending on their method **get_balance()** ?

## Edit

We can do a `fetch()` on the collection query in the template to retrieve transformed elements. How do you use observe() in this case ? Because in this case, reactivity is lost and addresses not updated.

**before**:

[image: no sorting]

```js
donationAddresses: ->
  coinsManager = Meteor.users.findOne
    "emails.address": "coinsmanager@gmail.com"
  if coinsManager
    Addresses.find
      userId: coinsManager._id
```

**after**:
[image: sorting]

```js
donationAddresses: ->
  coinsManager = Meteor.users.findOne
    "emails.address": "coinsmanager@gmail.com"
  if coinsManager
    addresses = Addresses.find
      userId: coinsManager._id
    addresses = addresses.fetch().sort (a, b) ->
      a = a.get_balance()
      b = b.get_balance()
      if not _.isNumber a
        a = -1
      if not _.isNumber b
        b = -1
      b - a
    return addresses
```

Comment: Not being super familiar with the API, is there some way you can place arguments to your `.find` in the helper. That way the sorting can happen server side, rather than what could be a messy client side sort. As long as your model implementation is accessible from the server that is

Comment: The biggest problem I see with this approach is that your transform function does an AJAX call. Every one of the docs returned by a cursor will get their own AJAX call, which is very inefficient. You can always do a `sort` in your template helper, which might sound inefficient but not as much as the AJAX issue.

Comment: Could you provide more info on what 3rd party API data you're retrieving?

Comment: Code is here: https://github.com/CoinsManager/CoinsManager/.  All addresses will call an api defined by the class they inherit. Eg a bitcoin address will inherit https://github.com/CoinsManager/CoinsManager/blob/alpha/app/models/cryptos/Bitcoin.coffee, and get the coin balance from http://blockexplorer.com/q/

Comment: I understand that having ajax calls in the transform isn't great, but I don't see a better way atm. When I'll host my own ledgers with my own api in a few months, then I can have the api run by meteor and do reactive sync.

@Cuberto In the template helper, results from the find() are still untransformed documents, that's why I thought {{#each}} was the best place to handle the sort.

Comment: @Fandekasp You can `fetch()` from the cursor and then sort the resulting array from within your helper. `find()` just returns a cursor, it doesn't actually retrieve the documents from the DB.

Comment: Correct, same answer as @Dan Dascalescu. Updated my post with a question for fixing reactivity through observe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it working!

[image: success]

And here is the code:

[image: code]

So basically,

- I moved the initialization of the collection cursor from the template to the router, and I return a **fetched** collection (array)
- I retrieve that collection in my template helper, and perform a sort on the array.
- I pass the sorted array to UI.each.

Not sure how I managed to handle the reactivity without observe or observeHandler... but it works. Probably the magic is handled from Iron router to keep the data reactive :)

Comment: This should be reactive - the only issue is that because you're  fetching the entire result set, a change to any result will cause the whole block to invalidate / re-render.

Comment: Yes, couldn't find a better solution. Fetching from the template kills the reactivity apparently.
We'll really appreciate if someone can do a PR to CoinsManager with an optimized version!

Comment: Meteor should [implement sort-after-transform in Minimongo](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/1852) <-- GitHub issue

Answer (score 1):

[Minimongo doesn't support sorting on virtual fields.](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/1852), so `Addresses.find({...}, {sort: {balanceVirtualField: 1}}` wont' work.

Can you `fetch()` the collection's `find()` result and sort the array? To preserve reactivity, you can [`observe()`](http://docs.meteor.com/#observe) it and recreate the array. Slow but might be a stop-gap measure until Meteor implements that feature.

Comment: You're correct, fetched items in the template have been transformed.
Updated my post to ask how to use observe in that case, because reactivity is lost

Comment: Couldn't find a way to use observe on my collection cursor from the router data, and I cannot retrieve the data within my template helper. Code can be tested at https://github.com/CoinsManager/CoinsManager/pull/41

Answer (score 1):

The following code will sync a source collection (`myCollection`) in to a local collection (`myLocalCollection`), and apply transforms on new / updated documents.

```
myCollection = new Meteor.Collection('myCollection')
myLocalCollection = new Meteor.Collection(null)

_myTransform = (doc)->
  doc.awesome = (doc.someProp > 3)
  return

_syncWithTransform = (destination, xform)->
  return {
    added: (doc)->
      destination.insert(xform(doc))
      return

    changed: (doc)->
      destination.update(id, xform(doc))
      return

    removed: (doc)->
      destination.remove(doc._id)
      return
  }

myCollection.find().observe(_syncWithTransform(myLocalCollection, _myTransform))
```

If you only want to perform your transform task when specific fields change, you can create two transform functions, and use `observeChanges` to check if a specific field was updated-

```
myCollection = new Meteor.Collection('myCollection')
myLocalCollection = new Meteor.Collection(null)

_transformNew = (doc)->
  doc.awesome = (doc.someProp > 3)
  return

_transformUpdate = ($modifier)->
  if $modifier.$set?.someProp?
    $modifier.$set.awesome = ($modifier.$set.someProp > 3)
  return $modifier

_syncWithTransform = (destination, xnew, xmod)->
  return {
    added: (id, fields)->
      fields._id = id
      destination.insert(xnew(fields))
      return

    changed: (id, fields)->
      $modifier = {}
      for key, value of fields
        if value == undefined
          unless $modifier.$unset?
            $modifier.$unset = {}
          $modifier.$unset[key] = true
        else
          unless $modifier.$set?
            $modifier.$set = {}
          $modifier.$set[key] = value
      destination.update(id, xmod($modifier))
      return

    removed: (id)->
      destination.remove(id)
      return
  }

myCollection.find().observeChanges(_syncWithTransform(myLocalCollection, _transformNew, _transformUpdate()))
```

Once you have the separate collection filled with the transformed documents - you can do regular reactive & sorted queries, eg. `myLocalCollection.find({},{sort:['a','b','c']})`

Comment: Sounds like a good solution :) Will test it. 

Why are we using transform via observe, and not the normal transform in a collection ?

Comment: Sorry, but this does not do what I want.

I want my collection to be transformed, and then be sorted by a new argument added in the transform, and stay reactive. your solution is still observing the original collection which docs do not have methods get_balance and get_value. Code can be tested at https://github.com/CoinsManager/CoinsManager/pull/41 (cf https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XxjvJjltHYo for installing and running the app)

Comment: You should use the mirrored collection from my example in your template helpers (`myLocalCollection`) - because you've mirrored the original collection, but with the transforms applied, it will have all the fields you need to sort by etc. and still be reactively linked to changes in the original data. - but the properties should be VALUES not functions.